# How to handle apt-get update failing to fetch old packages *without* upgrading

Tags: apt

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. When I try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`, I get a bunch of 404/Not Found and 403/Forbidden errors and it's preventing apt-get from working most of the time.

I can paste the full output if it's helpful, but here are just a few lines that might indicate the issue:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.basho.com/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.basho.com/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

I know that [Quantal reached end-of-life in May 2014](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/17/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-end-of-life-reached-on-may-16-2014/).

I don't really care about using Quantal stuff -- and in fact I'm not quite sure why these Quantal packages are here given that I'm using 13.04.

I don't want to upgrade to 14.

As a single isolated example, I'd like to install the default Java development kit:

```
user@device:~/ $ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

but this results in the above package errors, and more package errors if I try `apt-get update --fix-missing`, as noted.

How should I go about using apt-get to install the JDK without upgrading to a different version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Although it is possible, I think advising or supporting old releases is extremely bad advice, due to security flaws, such as shell shock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just edit your sources.list to point to the old-releases servers, as described in directions for EOL upgrades (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades), and proceed to install as you see fit.

A word of caution: you won't get any updates, even security related.  Even simple updates.  So, even though this is the answer to your question, it is still recommended that you upgrade to an LTS release.

Good luck.

Comment: You need to have root permissions to edit this file. To edit the file using Gedit paste this in the terminal `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` or if you want to use a text editor in the terminal `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: How do you upgrade to LTS?  We have a lot of servers with "Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Release 14.04", and update fails on all of them because of this Not Found error because the updates are no longer available.